# Parse header file into symbol table

Tags: c++, clang, symbols

Notice: I am not very familiar with the internal structure of Clang

Is it possible with Clang to parse a header file (And dependencies of this header file) into a symbol table and export (Could be a common file format) this table somehow?

Comment: define "export".  Also, here's a guide on how to write code to parse code.  https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/wiki/TutorialOrig

Comment: @xaxxon Edited, by export I meant writing to some file using a common format

Comment: Sure.. it's just a c++ program, so you can do anything you want once you have the data.  But it's not an easy process - so make sure you understand what you're getting into.  It's not a "clang++ --parse_my_header header.h"